# Dialog title change

Tags: jquery, html

I cant find the answer about jQuery dialog title. When the dialog title is set, I need to add in front of that string like "abc". When doing this $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "efg") dialog title changes to "abcdef". But this line $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "def") should not be changed at all. This is not the right answer for me:

```
var title = 'abc';
$("#dialog").dialog();
$("#dialog").dialog("option","title", title+"def");
```

I tried this, but it does not work for me:
html:

```
<div id="dialog">I'm in a dialog</div>
```

javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $("#dialog").attr("title",function(){return "abc" + this.title});
    $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","def");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by "def" shouldn't be changed at all....

That said, here's a solution where you poll for the current title, store it, and then append it.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#dialog").dialog();
       $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","def");
       var curTitle =  $("#dialog").dialog("option","title");
       //alert(curTitle);
       $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","abc" + curTitle); 
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbo6upxk/

---

UPDATE:

Ok, i think this is what you want to do:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Default Title">I'm in a dialog</div>
```

and js:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var curTitle =  $("#dialog").attr("title");
     alert(curTitle);
     $("#dialog").dialog();
     alert('see my default title?  i will change now!');
     $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","def");
     curTitle =  $("#dialog").dialog("option","title");
     alert(curTitle);
     $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","abc" + curTitle);   
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekc9r3hj/2/

---

Update 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();      
    $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","abc" + $("#dialog").dialog("option","title"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8y2jwwhs/1/

Comment: what I mean is that dialog is open already and when you open JS console and write this line: $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","def");
title in the open dialog changes to abcdef

Comment: Updated my answer.  Is this more in line what you are after?

Comment: not really. The title must change to abcdef whenever this line is called $("#dialog").dialog("option","title","def"); not after that